# laravel config:cache creates different cache file between first run and afterwards

Tags: php, laravel

I just run into curious behavior of laravel config:cache.
When I create a `.env` file with

```ini
APP_ENV=production
THIS_IS_TEST_1=1
THIS_IS_TEST_3=1
```

(not important lines are snipped, the same goes for the others.)

and I create `.env.production` like

```ini
APP_ENV=production
THIS_IS_TEST_1=2
THIS_IS_TEST_2=1
```

then I add lines to read `.env` value in config/app.php

```php
    'this_is_test_1' => env('THIS_IS_TEST_1', -1),
    'this_is_test_2' => env('THIS_IS_TEST_2', -1),
    'this_is_test_3' => env('THIS_IS_TEST_3', -1),
```

After that, I've typed command `./artisan config:cache`. It generates cache file as `bootstrap/cache/config.php` with values below.

```php
    'this_is_test_1' => '2',
    'this_is_test_2' => '1',
    'this_is_test_3' => '1',
```

So, at the first run of `./artisan config:cache` generates cache file with both `.env` and `.env.production`. And also values in `.env` overwritten by values in `.env.production`.

And then, this is most curious part, I've run `./artisan config:cache` following the first run generates cache file with values below.

```php
    'this_is_test_1' => '1',
    'this_is_test_2' => -1,
    'this_is_test_3' => '1',
```

This cache looks like based on `.env` and not on `.env.production`. After second run, `./artisan config:cache` generates cache only with `.env`.

When I run `config:clear` and clear the cache file, then `./artisan config:cache` generates config cache as same as first attempt.

```php
    'this_is_test_1' => '2',
    'this_is_test_2' => '1',
    'this_is_test_3' => '1',
```

Is this a normal and expected behavior of laravel?

I've placed entire example on github.
https://github.com/kent013/laravel-config-example
This example project is generated with `composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app` and just changed few lines to regenerate the behavior.

Any helps are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you saying it is ignoring `.env.production` in second run? It could be because the both files have same `APP_ENV=production`. May be you should try changing `APP_ENV` in the `.env` file.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I just removed `.env.prodction` from production build environment. I just wondering that this is a normal behavior or not.

Comment: @ISHITOYAKentaro Yes, it seems normal behavior. Did it work? Please accept the answer if it worked.